# ¿Cómo hacer el handle de un dropdown en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un dropdown sencillo en react. Mi state se ve de la siguiente manera:

```
this.state = {
          opciones: [
                {"id": 1, "descripcion": "Opcion 1"}
              , {"id": 2, "descripcion": "Opcion 2"}
              , {"id": 3, "descripcion": "Opcion 3"}
              , {"id": 4, "descripcion": "Opcion 4"}
              , {"id": 5, "descripcion": "Opcion 5"}
              , {"id": 6, "descripcion": "Opcion 6"}
          ],
          dropdown:null
      }
```

Y tengo un dropdown que se ve de esta manera:

```
<div>
     <label htmlFor="dropdown">Drop Down</label>
     <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onChange={this.handleOptionChange} value={this.state.dropdown}>
     {this.state.opciones.map(opt => {
           return <option value={opt.id}>{opt.descripcion}</option>
     })}
     </select>
</div>
```

Y tengo el siguiente handle:

```
handleOptionChange(e) {
      let target = e.target;
      this.setState({[target.name] : target.value}, console.log(this.state.dropdown));
  }
```

Pero a la hora de cambiar la opcion me cambia el id que estoy mandando pero tambien afecta al origen de datos (el arreglo opciones) el resultado es este:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="4">opcion 1</option>
    <option value="2">opcion 2</option>
    <option value="3">opcion 3</option>
    <option value="4">opcion 4</option>
    <option value="5">opcion 5</option>
    <option value="6">opcion 6</option>
</select>
```

No sé si estoy haciendo algo mal. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas agregar el key cuando hace el map de los options, un id unico. Ademas el value que estas asignadole al select esta demas.

```
   <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onChange={this.handleOptionChange}>
     {this.state.opciones.map(opt => {
           return <option key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>{opt.descripcion}</option>
     })}
     </select>
```

Tu handler quedaria mejor asi:

```
handleOptionChange(e) {
      const {name, value } = e.target;
      this.setState({[name] : value});
  }
```

Comment: te cuento que lo intenté y el problema persistía, entonces cree un nuevo proyecto de react y ahi si funcionó. Ni idea de que es lo que ocurría.

Comment: Que raro, yo copié exactamente tu código y me funcionó bien cuando apliqué los cambios que comenté